# Regarding enabling and disabling fields for registration form?

Tags: javascript

I have to create a registration form with fields as first name,last name,address,contact no,email.initially only first name shouid be visible as i enter name it should enable last name as i enter last name it should enable address

Comment: just a side note that is a terrible design from an users standpoint of view, it is just going to frustrate the user that he keeps getting surprise fields he also has to fill out.. Just saying..

Answer (score 0):

you could do somthing like this

```
<form>
  <input id='firstname' >
  <input id='lastname' disabled>
</form>

<script>
  const firsname = document.getElementById('firstname')
  const lastname = document.getElementById('lastname')

  firstname.oninput = function(){
    if(firstname.value.length>0) lastname.disabled = false 
    else lastname.disabled = true
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have totally different take on this. There is nothing wrong with this approach. In-fact there are many cool UIs design with same terminology. typeform.com is great example for this.

This is very bad practice at SO, whats a point in down rating a new user.

If you cant give a proper suggestion, then you have no right to down rate someone only because you failed to understand his view point.

To answer this :
It will be very bad idea if its just implemented this in wrong way, and user might get annoyed with this.

Its better to use combination of CSS and JS (jquery) to achieve this for great looking, user friendly UI.

Find this small snippet i've created using jQuery might help you.
with little css it can be made to look great!

**Press enter after entering detail into text box.**

```js
jQuery.extend(jQuery.expr[':'], {
  focusable: function(el, index, selector) {
    return $(el).is('a, button, :input,[tabindex]');
  }
}); // extention to jquery
$("#res").hide();
$("#email").hide();
$("#mobile").hide();
//Focuse Next on Enter press
$(document).on('keypress', 'input,select', function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $focusable = $(':focusable');
    var index = $focusable.index(document.activeElement) + 1;
    if (index >= $focusable.length) index = 0;
    $focusable.eq(index - 1).hide();
    $focusable.eq(index).show();
    $focusable.eq(index).focus();
  }
});

function subscribeRelease() {
  $("#res").show(200);
  $(".btn").hide(200);
}
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid h-100 justify-content-center">
  <div class="row justify-content-center align-middle h-100">
    <div class="col-10 text-center align-self-center">
      <h1 style="font-size:40pt;">Register</h1>
      <form id="register" class="form-inline justify-content-center">

        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name" /><br>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" /><br>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mobile" placeholder="Mobile" /><br>

        <br><br><br>
        <button class="btn btn-info" onclick="subscribeRelease(); return false;">Submit!</button>
        <span id="res"><h3 class="text-success">Registration Completed!</h3></span>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```